# Do strike aircraft turn off their datalink?

Tags: military, stealth, data-link

As far as I know, it is normal procedure for aircraft on a strike mission to go into radio silence at a certain point of the mission, as to not give of any unnecessary emissions that could warn the enemy of the aircraft's presence. I was wondering if this also applies to the datalink system or whether there is some kind of mode for the datalink in which the aircraft only receives datalink information, but doesn't transmit.

Comment: As long as it is satellite shared it should be no problem to recieve only. It's the same with the GPS signal, the fighters still recieve it, even when radio transmission is turned off.

Comment: But then you could for example not see your wingman on your datalink.

Comment: I think there are now some types of secret datalinks. One principle is using laser between the aircraft in the flight, another is using some form of direct spread spectrum to make it indistinguishable from noise for anybody without appropriate key. I am not sure how much either is already deployed.